# Navbar toggle button and dropdown menus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a navbar but it doesn't seem to be responsive. It only works to the extent that the **toggle button appears, but nothing happens when clicked**. Also, the **dropdown menu has no effect**. I've tried various solutions mentioned on other posts but nothing seems to be working.

I've included the scripts I've linked to at the end. Please help me identify where it's going wrong

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">GrapeVine</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#areas" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Areas<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#North">North</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#East">East</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#South">South</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#west">West</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


<script src="/js/myjQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootsrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error console on your browser for load errors? Quite useful to see if you scripts can't be found or you have an error in your code...

Comment: @TheSenator I didn't, but that's helpful for future issues - thank you. If you're able to, could you point me towards how I'd do that? 

Would be grateful, I'm still a beginner

Comment: it depends slightly on your browser. For example in Safari on a Mac, you go to the 'Develop' toolbar and select 'Show Error Console' which then brings up several tabs. Looking at the Network tab or Debugger tab can often provide useful insight into a load failure or an issue with a script. On Google Chrome on a PC I think its Ctrl+Shit+J to debug JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in your script source

replace this

```
/js/bootsrap.min.js
```

to

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! This worked. Out of interest, does it matter which version you link to? I tried linking to a maxcdn source earlier but didn't get a result (though I may have just linked incorrectly).

Comment: yeah.. and also it should be the same version of your bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js, you must try to work offline by downloading the files in bootstrap website.

Answer (score 0):

You have got "bootsrap" instead of "bootstrap" in your script source:

```
<script src="/js/bootsrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very good point! However it wasn't the issue, I think it happened after adding/changing the script source a couple of times. Good spot though :)